# How to mimic UINavigation animation behavior when transitioning between two UITableViews

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have a UIViewController that houses two UITableViews and swaps between the two. I'm wondering how can I implement the exact same animation behavior that a UINavigationController does when transitioning between these two UITableViews? (ie one tableView gets pushed off the screen left to right or right to left by the other tableView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Set table 2 up offscreen as starting state
CGRect rect = tableView2.frame;
rect.origin.x = rect.size.width;
tableView2.frame = rect;

// fill in any details you need for the animation
[UIView beginAnimation:...

// move 1 left offscreen
rect = tableView1.frame;
rect.origin.x = -rect.size.width;
tableView1.frame = rect;

// bring 2 right onscreen
rect = tableView2.frame;
rect.origin.x = 0;
tableView2.frame = rect;

[UIView commitAnimation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you cant use two UIViewController:s?

If not you should be able to do it by animating the bounds property of both table views. You could probaby also do it by using a paged scroll view and just switch beteween pages.

Comment: I needed these two views to swap in and out because they needed to fit under the same navigation title. If I animate them as seperate view controllers, the navigation header also animates even though the name stays the same, it looks funny.