# Simulate push view animation inside UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I have a single UIView with some labels that display attributes from objects inside an array. I'm using gesture recognizers to change the current element in the array and hence the text in the labels. My question is how do I mimic a push animation without actually pushing a new view controller. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this similar post:

[Pushing a tableview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590404/how-to-mimic-uinavigation-animation-behavior-when-transitioning-between-two-uitab/7590548#7590548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats simple way to use CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation to move any view from X axis to Y axis using UIViewAnimation. Before using this transition set your object frame to some x,y axis(0,0) and pass your x and y to move from.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x,y);

YOUR ViewOBJECT.transform=transform;


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the UIView class methods for animation? For example this could help:

`+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations`

In the animations block you could move one view out and another in.

Comment: That is my question how can I achieve that effect without adding any additional elements. I just want to present the same exact screen over and over with the transitions being animated. Thanks